# Are there accepted names for the two types of arrays in a multidimensional array?

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, 2d, convention

Sorry if this question is a bit elementary, but I was wondering if there are names for the different arrays in a 2D array. For example, in:

```
int[][] array = new int[5][10];
```

What do I call the array with the length of 5? And what about the arrays with the length of 10? I was thinking something like the "primary array" and "secondary array" since the secondary arrays are stored in the primary array...

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When looking at a multidimensional array (an array of arrays), the first length is the amount of rows there are. The second length is the amount of columns. So typically, say if running through a for loop, you could refer to them as such.

An example of a multidimensional array
int [][] arr = new int[2][3] could look like:

[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]

So there are [2] rows, of [3] columns.

Comment: Thanks. So you think one should be called the vertical array, and the other horizontal?

Comment: Really depends on what you're doing with the arrays. But visually, looking at it as rows and columns can help you choose a proper name. For instance if you are looking at a multidimensional array of letter grades for students, each row being a student and each column being a grade, these could be the names. What values are the arrays holding?

Comment: Visually speaking, I think vertical and horizontal makes sense in my case.